# Have you seen the Stack Notifier Apps?

Tags: discussion, notifications

Have you all seen these Stack Notifier Apps?

There are quite a few out there. Here are a couple which might come in handy. These are a good way to get notified when you receive a notice in SE:

- [Mac](https://stackapps.com/questions/3081/senotifier-a-stack-exchange-inbox-notifier-for-mac-os-x)
- [Windows](https://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-1-6-alpha-f)
- [Chrome](https://stackapps.com/questions/1592/stack-exchange-notifier-chrome-extension)

There are a bunch more here as well so, feel free to look for something which meets your needs:

http://stackapps.com

Comment: awesome thanks Nate!

Comment: thanks for this. Using SENotifier for Mac that you linked to, working well so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Awesome! Thank you for posting these. I'll be installing one shortly!